# How to switch per-chapter numbering to continuous numbering after a \chapter*{}?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How can I switch per-chapter numbering inside float elements to continuous numbering and avoiding the chapter number inside sectioning elements (section, subsection, etc) after a `\chapter*{}` declaration in a book?

I need a numbering like this:

```
CHAPTER 1
1.1 Section
1.1.1 Subsection
Figure 1.1

UNNUMBERED CHAPTER
1 Section
1.1 Subsection
Figure 1
```

I need this only for one unnumbered chapter inside the book, not for all of them. The reason is that I need a unnumbered section (with a chapter level) followed by numbered sections and floats without the previous chapter number. So required by document layout rules.

Comment: Is the unnumbered chapter the final one or others will follow it?

Comment: @egreg Can be followed by appendices and/or glossary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to change manually in proper places the behaviour of sections, as in the following example. If, in the example, the next chapter after unnumbered had to have number 3, one should uncomment `\stepcounter{chapter}`.
*If figures and tables are needed, please add also changes from egreg's comment.*

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{first}

\section{second}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\chapter*{Unnumbered}

\section{first}

\section{second}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
%\stepcounter{chapter}
\chapter{Second?}

\section{first}

\section{second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also `\thefigure` and `\thetable` should be changed; since the unnumbered chapter is the last one, doing `\stepcounter{chapter}` will reset the related counters; redefining also `\thesection` will do the right thing also for lower level sectional levels.

Comment: I just noticed that adding the hyperref package appears a warning: _pdfTeX warning (ext4): pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{section.1.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored_. Generates a problem with PDF bookmarks, how do I fix it?